# Use AJAX with HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

The AJAX call that should happen when clicking the button does not work.

This is the button HTML:

```html
<td><button id=${data[i].id} name="update" type="button" value="${data[i].id}" class="btn btn-primary update">update</button></td>
<td><button id=${data[i].id} name="drop" type="button" value="${data[i].id}" class="btn btn-primary drop">drop</button></td>
```

This is the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".drop").click(function() {
    const corseid = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(corseid);
    $.ajax({
      type: "delete",
      url: `/api/v1/courses/3`,
      success: function(res) {
        alert(`course deleted ${res}`)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: improve the readability of the post

Comment: This is the ajax code: jquery follows... You should tag accordingly this is not a Node.js question and primarily a jQuery question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have multiple buttons with the same `id`

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work". Is anything being printed in the console? Is the event handler at least being called?

Comment: Also, what is this code doing: `id=${data[i].id}`? Are you using a framework, or is this HTML being added as a string somewhere by your JS?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it with jquery?

Here is example doing button click plain javascritp:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="buttonClicked(this)" id="2" value="1001"/>
</body>
</html>

<script type="javascript">
//Runnin function as asyncronous to not stop other site usage
async function buttonClicked (obj) {
    console.log(e);
    var value = obj.value // example how you get other info from button object
    var url = 'http://www.url.com/rest'
    var resturl = url + '/api/v1/courses/' + obj.id
    await axios.delete(resturl) // has to be url to api "http://www.url.com/rest/api/v1/courses/1" till example
    .then((response) => alert('Course deleted: ' + response.data)
}
</script>
```

Comment: courses?submit=submit:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at buttonClicked (courses?submit=submit:74:18)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (courses?submit=submit:1:1)
buttonClicked @ courses?submit=submit:74
onclick @ courses?submit=submit:1

Comment: i got this error on conslo.log and tell me that it cant read  '''const id =e.id'''

Comment: Edited to display what belongs and where.

Comment: Added also now axios delete command to use plain javascript.